# Switching from SVN to Mercurial: one repository or many?

Tags: version-control, svn, mercurial

We currently have a large Subversion repository, with a tree like:

```
root
    /libraries
        /library1
            /trunk
        /library2
            /trunk
    /solutions
        /solution1
            /trunk
        /solution2
            /trunk
```

There are 81 solutions and 22 libraries.  The `trunk` subdirectories were added so we could use branches, but in practice, we don't use branches at all.

My question is: if we migrate this to Mercurial, should be set up one big Mercurial tree with the same structure?  Or should we create 81+22 Mercurial repositories?

Answer (score 3):

Why not something in between? I strongly suspect the libraries should be subrepos (a bit like external in svn)

The solutions could either be seperate repos if they are unrelated, or if there is some relation between them, perhaps named branches in one (or a few repos)